# Why is .NET loading an assembly when I'm not referencing any types in that assembly?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-assembly

I have a codebase which contains an MVC projects, two WCF projects, and a service layer (business objects, repositories, etc).  I also have an assembly of common code (which I'll just call common) which contains code that is

a) Shared among the code base
and
b) Code that is intended to be reused in other projects.

Part of this common code is a namespace I call Common.Web, which contains MVC attributes that are used in my current MVC app, and that I wrote intending to use in future apps (things like audit logging, etc).

Anyway, my WCF services have been happily referencing my common assembly for months.  They obviously don't use any of the classes that need to reference System.Web.Mvc.dll, because, well, they don't reference anything in those classes, so .NET won't try to load System.Web.Mvc.dll.

However, today I came across a problem.  I added code to my Common assembly that is called from one of my WCF services.This code writes to a database via EF Code First.  It is a simple class (and DbContext) which look like this:

```
using System.Data.Entity;
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace Rsts.Common.Clients.Transcend
{
    public class TransactionAuditContext : DbContext
    {

        public TransactionAuditContext(string connString)
            : base(connString)
        {

        }

        /// <summary>
        /// DbSet of AuditEventTypes
        /// </summary>
        public DbSet<TransactionDetails> Transactions { get; set; }

    }

    public class TransactionDetails
    {

        [Key()]
        public Int64 TransactionID { get; set; }

        public Int64 PageRequestID { get; set; }

        public string TransactionRequestData { get; set; }

        public string TransactionReturnData { get; set; }

    }
}
```

As soon as I execute code like this:

```
context.Transactions.Add(new TransactionDetails());
```

I get a ReflectionTypeLoadException and the reason is because System.Web.Mvc.dll is not found.  I DO reference System.Web.Mvc.dll in my Common dll, but this code doesn't reference any types in System.Web.Mvc.dll so there should be no reason that I know of for .NET to try and load MVC.

When I look at the Types property of the ReflectionTypeLoadException, it seems like .NET is trying to load EVERY type in my Common assembly, whether I'm using it or not.  So, is there any situation that would cause .NET to load EVERY type in an assembly?  Is there a point where an assembly is referenced so many times that .NET will just load EVERY type in the assembly?  (Remember this is my Common assembly so it's referenced a lot).

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The Entity Framework is likely reflecting all referenced DLL's...for whatever reason, who knows.  There's a known issue that looks similar: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/588847/random-unable-to-load-one-or-more-of-the-requested-types-errors

Comment: You referenced the common assembly, and are promised the ability to create and work with all of its objects by the runtime, which in turn means bringing in all the supporting assemblies they reference. Just because you currently don't use those certain types that need MVC doesn't mean you aren't explicitly asking the runtime for that ability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One case when extra assemblies are being loaded (not all referenced once) is Assembly.GetTypes() and you have types that derive from types in non-existing assembly. Normally such code would run ok if you don't use these types, but as soon as something calls GetTypes() it will fail.

Comment: My stack trace for the exception ends at System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.GetTypes(), which, combined with the comment above about Entity Framework reflecting over the referenced dlls, is probably the root of the problem.  Is there anyway to have .NET or EF ignore a specific type or types?

Comment: @jeff.eynon, not to my knowledge. In your own code you can dig through assembly metadata by hand... similar to what ILDasm and other decomilers do  but it is not fun. Bringing in all dependencies is the only sane way I know.

Comment: Sounds like the best approach then might be to replace my EF codecwith some old school ado.net :) That fixes it here but I'd hate to make my permenant solution be no EF in this assembly.